# Как отправить POST запрос, и достать результат?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть следующий ресурс https://porfirevich.ru/, в поле вводится какая-либо строка, отпраляется POST запрос, и возвращается строка с результатом, и я собственно говоря не могу разобраться как мне самому отправить этот POST запрос и достать соответствующую строку

```
response = requests.post("https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/", data=)
```

Я не понимаю как собрать запрос так, чтобы он корректно выполнился

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
import json


url = "https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/"

msg = "Твой текст!"
data = {"prompt": msg}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data)).json()
answer = response.get("replies")
print(*answer)
```

```
Что такое «Западное оружие»?  Ты именно за это его и выдала, за свой корявый русскоязычный ф  Твой текст! Твоя жизнь!» — кричал первый голос.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, добавил еще пару параметров, и работает идеально